# Function accepts 1,2,3 but doesn't accept string '1,2,3'?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using the google visualization charts api but I believe this is some kind of javascript mistake I am making. I populate this array with numbers:

```
visibleRows = [];
```

And make it a comma delimted string:

```
visibleRows.join(',');
```

console.logging visibleRows after this gives:

```
0,1,3
```

But when I feed visibleRows into the function the very next line:

```
pieViewHits.setRows([visibleRows]);
```

I get the error: Invalid row index 0,1,3 Should be in the range [0-3] **BUT** if I replace all the above code with just:

```
pieViewHits.setRows([0,1,3]);
```

It works perfectly! Any ideas?

Comment: This is not C, a `String` is not an `Array`...

Comment: visibleRows.join(','); transforms the array into a comma delimited string.

Comment: this doesn't modify the fact that strings are not arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[0,1,3]` is an array containing three numbers

`visibleRows.join(',');` returns a comma delimited string. You aren't assigning it anywhere, so it doesn't do anything.

`[visibleRows]` is an array *containing a second array* that contains three numbers in turn. It will be flattened to a comma delimited string if used in a string context.

The function expects an array containing three numbers, not an array containing another array or an array containing a comma delimited string.

Just pass the array without wrapping it in another array or `join`ing it.

```
visibleRows = [];
visibleRows.push(0);
visibleRows.push(1);
visibleRows.push(3);
pieViewHits.setRows(visibleRows);
```

Answer (score 0):

`visibleRows` is already an array, so you don't have to pass it as `[visibleRows]` (within box bracket).

Change

```
pieViewHits.setRows([visibleRows]);
```

to

```
pieViewHits.setRows(visibleRows);
```

And I don't think you need to use, `visibleRows.join(',');`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. visibleRows.join(','); transforms the array into a comma delimited string.

Comment: @Hardworker I understand. ` visibleRows.join(',');` returns array to string. ` visibleRows` is not transformed to string, it's still an array.

Comment: Nope visibleRows becomes a string once you run that join

Comment: `visibleRows` does not transforms to string. You can check out the MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: `.join()` converts array to string and returns the converted values to the assigned variable. For Ex: `str= visibleRows.join(',');`. Here `str` is a string and `visibleRows` is an array.

Comment: @Hard Worker - It doesn't. the join function returns a string but does not change the visibleRows array.